# Firebase not worked on real devices (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, firebase

I install Firebase in my iOS app. 
Everything works fine on simulator but on real device it doesn't execute / return a query to my database.

I try to clean the project but it doesn't change anything.

Have you a solution ?

EDIT : Update with code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setup Firebase
    self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()



    self.ref.child("Database").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in


        if snapshot.exists() {
            for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                print(rest.value)


            }
        } else {


        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post your code before we can even speculate what is wrong

Comment: I edited my post. It's working on simulator but not on my iPhone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fault in your code, I had the same problem. Here is what I did:

1. Simply go to Your Project in the navigation pane on the left.
2. Go to **Build Settings** and scroll down to **Build Options**.
3. Change the value of **Enable Bitcode** to **No**.

Hope it works out for you too!

Comment: @user1585646 none of these answers helped me. But i'm explicitly logged out from real device and then sign in again, and DB immediately start responding. I think Firebase cached key and didn't renew it properly.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you logged in, and delete the application, then after you install the application again, you will still be logged in. I do not know exactly, but I assumed that Firebase somehow binds the account cache to the Bundle Identifier, not in the local storage.

So the solution is simple and it worked for me:

1. Remove the your APP from real device.
2. Go to your project in Navigation Panel.
3. In General tab change your Bundle identifier, for example: "myApp.com" to "myApplication.com" or whatever you want.
4. Build and run
5. Bingo! Now your app should interact well with Firebase again.

Update: 
Firebase remembers your login in the keychain

Update: 
Firebase remembers your data in keychain using your Bundle identifier as key

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was due to **Authentication**. **Authentication** was **Enable** on **Firebase** but I have not **Authenticate User**. So I was not able to read the Node from **Firebase Database**.